# ParametricPlot: Can't use Ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

So, basically I'm trying to plot the phase portrait of a `2x2` diff system, but the parameters are a pain. I'm trying to get a good picture of the orbits, but even if I use `FrameTicks`, *Mathematica* just ignores me.
So this is the code:

```
Clear[n1, n2, i, L]

system4 = {D[n1[t], t] == (r1*n1[t])*(1 - (n1[t]/(k1 + L[t])) - 
                ((α12*n2[t])/(k1 + L[t]))) - (c1*i[t]*n1[t]), 
           D[n2[t], t] == (r2*n2[t])*(1 - (n2[t]/k2) - ((α21*n1[t])/k2)), 
           D[i[t], t] == s - (d1*i[t]) + ((ρ*i[t]*n1[t])/(γ + n1[t])) - 
                (c2*i[t]*n1[t]), 
           D[L[t], t] == (σ*L[t]) + (ϕ*n1[t]) - (ω*n1[t]*L[t])};

L[t_] = 0; ϕ = 0;

n2[t_] = 10^12;

system2 = Table[system4[[m]], {m, {1, 3}}];

incognitas2 = {n1[t], i[t]};

incognitas4 = {n1[t], n2[t], i[t], L[t]};

ci2 = {n1[0] == 100, i[0] == 10};

r1 = 10^(-2);

k1 = 10^(8);

α12 = 9*(10^(-5));

c1 = 10^(-9);

r2 = 10^(-3);

k2 = 10^(12);

α21 = 9*(10^(-2));

s = 0;

d1 = .2;

γ = 100;

c2 = 10^(-10);

ρ = .206;

tfinal = 10000000;

Module[{c = 0}, 
      sol = NDSolve[Join[system2, ci2], incognitas2, {t, 0, tfinal}, 
      MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> {StiffnessSwitching, 
      Method -> {ExplicitRungeKutta, Automatic}}, PrecisionGoal -> 15,
      StepMonitor :> c++]; c];

sol1[t_] = First[n1[t] /. sol];

sol2[t_] = First[i[t] /. sol];
```

And I want to plot `sol2` vs `sol1`; Axes from `0` to `10^7`, pref using the ticks `0,10,10^2,..10^5,10^6,10^7`, and both `sol1` and `sol2` depend on `t`, I want to run `t` form `0` to `100 000`.
Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using `ScalingFunctions` to get logarithmic scaling:

```
ParametricPlot[{sol1[t], sol2[t]}, {t, 0, 100000},
 AspectRatio -> 1, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 How can I find about the usage of option `ScalingFunctions`.

Comment: @JunhoLee, there is a page in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) for it. Officially it's only supported for charting functions but it seems to work for `ParametricPlot` too.